# How to configure Neo4j shell?

Tags: neo4j

I am new for neo4j, I have already installed in my pc `neo4j-community_windows-x64_2_2_5` version. So I want to use the neo4j-shell command. Any help?

Comment: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-starting.html

Answer (score 1):

For the windows installer the shell is on the options pane as "Command Prompt" button.

[image]

Comment: [tag:MichaelHunger] Thank you, I got it now.